# A Question Regarding Ordinal Turing Machines

Tags: set-theory, computability, philosophy

Consider the following theorem of Koepke:

'A set x of ordinals is ordinal computable from a finite set of ordinal parameters if and only if it is an element of the constructible universe L".

Taking the contrapositive of each implication in the above biconditional one has (this thanks to Andreas Blass):

'A set x of ordinals is not ordinal computable from a finite set of ordinal parameters if and only if it [i.e. x--my comment] is not constructible'.

A few questions spring to mind:

a) Can ordinal Turing machines only compute from a finite set of ordinal parmeters?

b) If not, can the ordinal computation (using ordinal Turing machines) of a set x of ordinals from an infinite set of ordinal parameters, if x can only be computed from an infinite set of ordinal parameters, imply that x is nonconstructible (from Prof. Blass' 'contrapositive' reformulation of Koepke's theorem, the answer would seem to be 'yes' since x is not computable from a finite set of ordinal parameters)?

c) What features would an ordinal Turing machine have to have in order to ordinal compute from an infinite set of ordinal parameters?

This is a reformulation of my earlier post on ordinal Turing machines which unfortunately was not well received.  I hope this is a better formulation.

Comment: In general you need to be careful with giving an infinite amount of unrestricted information to a model of computation. For example, allowing $\omega$ many ordinal parameters will make all subsets of $\omega$ computable, simply by coding the characteristic function into the parameters (this is similar to what happens if we allow infinitely many states in any of the Turing-like models).

Comment: @Miha:  Are you in essence saying that giving an infinite amount of unrestricted information to a model of computation makes computation trivial?  If so, then how can one restrict the amount of information a computation has so as to make computation nontrivial but still allow the model to compute with an infinite set of parameters?

Comment: Whether this makes computation trivial or not depends on what you want computations to do. Perhaps you're willing to accept that sets of a certain size become computationally trivial in order to gain more power over larger sets. Also, allowing infinitely many parameters ties the computational strength to the set-theoretic background; e.g. while ordinal Turing machines compute $L$, I would conjecture that any reasonable generalization to infinitely many parameters would compute $L[\mathrm{Ord}^\omega]$.

Comment: I would like a reasonable generalization of ordinal Turing machines to infinitely many parameters to generate (in analogy to r.e. sets in ordinary recursion theory) nonconstructible sets.  If your conjecture is proved true, does $\math L[Ord^{omega}]$ contain nonconstructible sets?  Forgive my honest ignorance but I am not familiar wiith that particular model of ZFC(?) Any references you could give me regarding that particular model would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It depends, which is what I meant by my remark that allowing infinitely many parameters ties computational strength to the background set theory. For example, if $V=L$ then no strength is gained, but if there are reals not in $L$ then these will become computable. In general the closeness of $V$ and $L[\mathrm{Ord}^\omega]$ is tied to large cardinals (and with enough large cardinals even choice fails in this model), so this leads to the awkward situation where you can change computational strength by forcing, passing to inner models etc.

Comment: @Miha:  Very interesting.  One would have hoped that the situation would have been the other way 'round, that is, that the notion of 'machine' would have been more intuitive than the notion of 'set'.  To use a simple-minded hypothetical example, let the infinite set of ordinal parameters allow one to generate all of the constructible reals (if I understand correctly, one can generate all $\omega_1$ constructible reals from the countable ordinals) and then use the constructible reals as parameters in the following computation:  generating a countable set of integers different from all

Comment: the constructible reals.  If one assumes the existence of a measurable cardinal (since that implies that the set of all constructible reals is countable) then one can seeming generate a nonconstructible real by simple diagonalization (in the case where the existence of a measurable cardinal is not assumed the construction may be more difficult).  In this case (provided my hypothetical 'computation' is not utter nonsense) it would seem that the notion of 'machine' would be more fundamental (and more intuitive) than the notion of 'set'.  I wonder if ordinary recursion theory may be as

Comment: dependent on the background set theory if only we were able to look deeply enough....